# i want to open my file when download completed

Tags: javascript, android-download-manager, parcelfiledescriptor

I extracted some urls by jsoup.

and made a download manager.

and it seems parcelfiledescriptor doesn't work.

i tryed regist broadcaster but did't work.

I don't know where should I insert "parcelfiledescriptor" and "regist broadcaster"

i have no idea to fix this...

ps. these urls goes like this

"http://www.dhu.ac.kr/korean/HOME/bbs/bbs_download.php?mv_data=aWR4PTI3MDU0MyZzdGFydFBhZ2U9MCZsaXN0Tm89MjY2JnRhYmxlPWV4X2Jic19kYXRhX2RodWxpZmUmbmF2X2NvZGU9ZGh1MTM0NDQwODk1NCZjb2RlPWZvb2Qmc2VhcmNoX2l0ZW09JnNlYXJjaF9vcmRlcj0mb3JkZXJfbGlzdD0mbGlzdF9zY2FsZT0mdmlld19sZXZlbD0mdmlld19jYXRlPSZ2aWV3X2NhdGUyPQ==||&type=0&download=h"

is there any methods to open this url without Excel viewer?
 "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url= url" does'nt work

```js
package develop_hong.haanyeat;

import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class menucrawl extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String htmlPageUrl = "http://www.dhu.ac.kr/korean/HOME/dhulife/sub/sub.htm?nav_code=dhu1344408954"; //파싱할 홈페이지의 URL주소
    private String text = "";
    private String fixedtext = "";
    private String fixplus = "";
    private Button button1;
    private Button button2;
    private Button button3;
    private Button button4;
    private long downloadID;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menucrawl);

       


        Button button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(menucrawl.this, "1주차 메뉴를 다운로드 중입니다", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                new JsoupAsyncTask().execute();



            }


        });
        Button button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(menucrawl.this, "2주차 메뉴를 다운로드 중입니다", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                new JsoupAsyncTask2().execute();

            }


        });
        Button button3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(menucrawl.this, "3주차 메뉴를 다운로드 중입니다", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                new JsoupAsyncTask3().execute();

            }


        });
        Button button4 = findViewById(R.id.button4);
        button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(menucrawl.this, "4주차 메뉴를 다운로드 중입니다", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                new JsoupAsyncTask4().execute();


            }


        });


    }


    private class JsoupAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(htmlPageUrl).timeout(5000).get();
                Elements a = doc.select("tbody tr:has(a):eq(3) td:eq(2) a[href]");
                text = a.attr("href");
                String fixtext = text;
                fixedtext = fixtext.substring(5);
                fixplus = "http://www.dhu.ac.kr/korean/HOME" + fixedtext;
                System.out.println(fixplus);

                DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(fixplus));
                request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI |
                        DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);


                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

//set the local destination for download file to a path within the application's external files directory
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "me1nu.xlsx");
                request.setMimeType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
              downloadManager.enqueue(request);


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {


        }
    }

    private class JsoupAsyncTask2 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(htmlPageUrl).timeout(5000).get();
                Elements a = doc.select("tbody tr:has(a):eq(2) td:eq(2) a[href]");
                text = a.attr("href");
                String fixtext = text;
                fixedtext = fixtext.substring(5);
                fixplus = "http://www.dhu.ac.kr/korean/HOME" + fixedtext;
                System.out.println(fixplus);

                DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(fixplus));
                request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI |
                        DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);


                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

//set the local destination for download file to a path within the application's external files directory
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "me2nu.xlsx");
                request.setMimeType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
                downloadManager.enqueue(request);


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {


        }
    }

    private class JsoupAsyncTask3 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(htmlPageUrl).timeout(5000).get();
                Elements a = doc.select("tbody tr:has(a):eq(1) td:eq(2) a[href]");
                text = a.attr("href");
                String fixtext = text;
                fixedtext = fixtext.substring(5);
                fixplus = "http://www.dhu.ac.kr/korean/HOME" + fixedtext;
                System.out.println(fixplus);

                DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(fixplus));
                request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI |
                        DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);


                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

//set the local destination for download file to a path within the application's external files directory
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "me3nu.xlsx");
                request.setMimeType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
                downloadManager.enqueue(request);


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {


        }


    }


    private class JsoupAsyncTask4 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(htmlPageUrl).timeout(5000).get();
                Elements a = doc.select("tbody tr:has(a):eq(0) td:eq(2) a[href]");
                text = a.attr("href");
                String fixtext = text;
                fixedtext = fixtext.substring(5);
                fixplus = "http://www.dhu.ac.kr/korean/HOME" + fixedtext;
                System.out.println(fixplus);


                DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(fixplus));
                request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI |
                        DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);

// set title and description

                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

//set the local destination for download file to a path within the application's external files directory
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "me4nu.xlsx");
                request.setMimeType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
                downloadManager.enqueue(request);


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {


        }


    }

}
```

Comment: You will find this [Here](https://www.dslreports.com/forum/r21478709-)